# Port, Export & Implementation Port in UVM

Tags: uvm

What is exactly a port, export & implementation port in UVM??

I know something like port initiates the data transfer by calling a method, whose definition must be there in an implementation port connected to it. But still I don't know exact difference.

When to use put port/export/implementation port and similarly get port/export/implementation port, analysis port/export & analysis/tlm fifo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A TLM port defines the set of methods to be used for a particular connection, while a TLM export supplies the implementation of those methods. Connecting a port to an export allows the implementation to be executed when the port method is called

Any TLM communication involves mainly of two components, the producer and consumer. The producer generates transactions and the consumer receives the transactions.

- put-port allows a producer to put a transaction to consumer.
- get-port allows a consumer to request a transaction from a producer.
- Analysis ports are used when a producer needs to simultaneously send (broadcast) to multiple consumers. This is a non-blocking mode of communication.
- TLM Fifos are used when the consumer wants to store the received transactions and process them at a later time.

More detailed and in-depth information can be found in the user guide that came with the UVM 1.0 Reference Implementation. You can download the same http://www.accellera.org/downloads/standards/uvm

Comment: Thanks Vineeth, but I have a doubt. If it is all about producer & consumer, then we will require only port & export/implementation port (either of two). But what is the significance of the remained third port?

Comment: @MaheshShah ; you are confusing with the terminologies. there is only port and implementation. the implementation is normally referred to as export. Please read through the section 2.2.1 TLM-1 Implementation in the UVM user guide (not reference manual)